# Laravel 8 Serialization of 'PDO' is not allowed

Tags: laravel-8

I'm having a issue with my login controller. When I login it give's the message in the title. If I change the redirect to return a view it works but the url shows the previous url.

Code:

```
protected function authenticated(Request $request, $user)
    {
        if(Auth::check()) {
            if(Auth::user()->hasRole(['admin-user', 'super-user'])) {
                $users = User::where('id', '!=', \auth()->user()->id);
                return redirect()->to('/admin_dashboard')->with(compact('users'));
            }else {
                return redirect('/home');
            }
        }
    }
```

I'm using spatie-permissions and two roles admin-user and super-user.

I have a AdminDashboardController with only on method

```
public function index() {
return view('admin.admin_dashboard');
}
```

If I comment the code inside the authenticated method it logs in fine, but I need it to redirect to admin page if admin-user or super-user roles are present. I set a breakpoint inside the if statement and it goes to the redirect->to. Don't know what I'm doing wrong.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I ran into the same error, but for a different reason.

You are receiving this error because you are trying to serialize a Query Builder instance. You can only serialize a Collection/Model.

```
$users = User::where('id', '!=', \auth()->user()->id);
```

This will return a Builder instance, so edit that to:

```
$users = User::where('id', '!=', \auth()->user()->id)->get();
```